# Convert Tab Separated csv using unoconv

Tags: linux, csv, libreoffice

I am attempting to convert a tab separated `csv` into an `xls` file using `unoconv`. However, the tabs are not being recognized as the field separator. Can someone please tell me how this can be done.

I've tried:

`unoconv -i 09,,system,1 -f xls original.csv`

and I get the following error:

```
Warning: Option 09,,system,1 cannot be parsed, ignoring.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing FilterOptions. I think the correct command is:

```
unoconv -i FilterOptions=09,,system,1 -f xls original.csv
```